# How to always make all files/folders visible using 'ls' command?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I don't want to unhide just one folder at a time like `/usr`, `/Users`, `/path/to/whatever`.  I want to be able to see everything rather than the pains of using the chflags every time I can't see a folder...OR I may not know a folder exists if I'm a new OS X user so for discovery purposes as well.

Comment: A folder hidden by `chflags` is always visible with `ls`. I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set up an alias to automatically add `-a` to all `ls` invocations.

You can set up an alias in your .profile/.bashrc/.bash_aliases file (or wherever you so choose to have aliases defined, by default, I think OS X has them in .bashrc). Just add the following line, then run `source <filename>` to reload its configs or start up a new terminal window.

```
alias ls='ls -a'
```

Comment: @WeDoTDD If this answer works for you, mind marking it as an accepted solution? Thanks! :)

Comment: that's weird, I can't see the usr folder still or my profile folder but i can now see the rest like .trash, etc.

Comment: must have not been at the root, did a cd / and I'm good.